# How to add image with sliding menu

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I am following below link to implement sliding menu in android.

[Tutorial make your own Sliding Menu in Android](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/151)

and for downloading source code i have used below link.

https://github.com/onmyway133/SlidingMenu

So i am successfully able to implement with the basic sliding menu. But my question is how can i add image with each option.

[image]

So basically i want to add image with each option like Main, Button, Checkbox etc... So how can i add image with this.

I tried with some method but not get success. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own adaptater to the list view with custom xml for each row ,like this  :
[Listview tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)